# Improve C code with Neon iOS

Tags: ios, performance, simd, neon

The code below used to scale an image, but the performance is not good. I googled and found some advice to convert the codes to Neon ASM to get better performance.

```
inline void insetw32(char *pb_dst, char *pb_pFore, char *pb_pBack, char *pmix, int w)
{
    register char bbm = (char)(pmix[0]<<24>>24);
    for(int i = 0;i< w;i++)
    {
        *pb_dst++ = (((*pb_pFore++ - *pb_pBack++) * bbm)>>8) + *pb_pBack;
        *pb_dst++ = (((*pb_pFore++ - *pb_pBack++) * bbm)>>8) + *pb_pBack;
        *pb_dst++ = (((*pb_pFore++ - *pb_pBack++) * bbm)>>8) + *pb_pBack;
        *pb_dst++ = (((*pb_pFore++ - *pb_pBack++) * bbm)>>8) + *pb_pBack;
    }
}
```

I tried to translate the code with NEON, the performance is 2x faster than C language, but the same code I used MMX can get 4x faster on x86 platform, is there any other good way to improve that? Or is there any mistake in my NEON code?

```
        uint8x8_t fac1 = vdup_n_u8(bbm);
    int16x8_t fac = vmovl_u8(fac1);
    w /= 2; // 8/ 4
    while (w--)
    {
        int8x8_t temp8;
        int16x8_t  temp16;
        uint8x8_t rgbaFore  = vld1_u8(pb_pFore);
        uint8x8_t rgbaBack  = vld1_u8(pb_pBack);
        uint8x8_t rgbaDst  = vld1_u8(pb_dst);
        int16x8_t fore = vmovl_u8(rgbaFore);
        int16x8_t back = vmovl_u8(rgbaBack);
        temp16 = vsubq_s16(fore, back);
        temp16 = vmulq_s16(temp16, fac);
        temp8 = vshrn_n_s16(temp16, 8);
        temp8 = vadd_u8(temp8, rgbaBack);

        vst1_u8(pb_dst, temp8);

        pb_dst += 8;
        pb_pFore += 8;
        pb_pBack += 8;
    }
```

Comment: Although there is not much evidence of the OP having put much effort into this, I think it's still a potentially interesting question - voting to reopen.

Comment: There are a number of APIs available on iOS to handle scaling and other common image processing tasks efficiently; almost certainly one of the available APIs is suitable for your needs here.  Look into CoreGraphics, vImage, and CoreImage.  You might also have a look at Brad Larson's GPUImage framework.

Comment: Use the vsubl_u8() intrinsic to remove 2 instructions (vmovl_u8) from your loop. You can subtract and widen in one shot.